# Regular Expression not working - Online form validation and submission

Tags: javascript, regex, forms

So Im having trouble with my form. There are numurous validation techniques set up.
Two of my most obvious problems are an alert that pops upen at the start of the program but should only pop up if an onblur() is activated and my update() function returns a false value.
And aswell, my regular Expressions insist on providing me with false condition when I test them against my strings.
The finished form should validate various information and update values placed in the expenses inputs.
Really stuck on this...

```js
window.onload = initPage;

/*initPage() 
Initializes the contents of the Web page */

function initPage() {

//declare array variable dataFields points to input elements from the expenseEntry class
   
   var dataFields = new Array();

   var allElems = document.getElementsByTagName("*");

   for( var i = 0; i < allElems.length; i ++) {
      if(allElems[i].className == "expenseEntry") dataFields.push(allElems[i]);
   }

//add onblur event that runs update() function whenever focus leaves a datafield.

   for(var i = 0; i < dataFields.length; i++) {
      dataFields[i].onblur = update();
   }

//event handler that runs validateForm() upon submitting the form.

   document.forms[0].onsubmit = validateForm;
}

/* testLength() 
Tests a field for its length. */

function testLength(field) {
   if (field.value.length == 0) {

// Change the background color to white or yellow depending on the lenght.
      
      field.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
      return false;
   } 

   else field.style.backgroundColor = "white";
   return true; 
}

/* testPattern() 
Tests a field for its pattern. */

function testPattern(field, regx) {
   if (regx.test(field)) {
      field.style.backgroundColor = "white";
      field.style.color = "black";
      return true;
   }
   else field.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
        field.style.color = "red";
        return false;
}

/* validateForm() 
Validates a Web form */

function validateForm() {
   
   var isValid = true;

//testLength function with lname field also for fname, address, and summary to make sure an entry has been made.

   if (testLength(document.forms[0].lname) == false) {

        isValid = false;}

    if (testLength(document.forms[0].fname) == false) {

        isValid = false;}

    if (testLength(document.forms[0].address) == false) {

        isValid = false;}

    if (testLength(document.forms[0].summary) == false) {

        isValid = false;}

//must match ACT followed by six digits

   if (testPattern(document.forms[0].account,/^ACT\d{6}$/) == false)

    {isValid = false;}

//dept field. regx should match DEPT followed by three digits

    if (testPattern(document.forms[0].department.value,/^DEPT\d{3}$/) == false)

    {isValid = false;}   

//Project field with regx should match PROJ followed by five digits

    if (testPattern(document.forms[0].project,/^PROJ\d{5}$/) == false)

    {isValid = false;}

//call testPattern function to test SSN.  match 9 digits or text string

    if (testPattern(document.forms[0].ssn,/^\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}$/) == false)
      {isValid = false;}

   if (isValid == false)

    {alert("Please fill out all required fields in the proper format.");}

   return isValid;
}

/* calcRow 
Calculates the costs within one row of the travel report */

function calcRow(row) {
   
   var travel = parseFloat(document.forms[0].elements["travel"+row].value);

   var lodge = parseFloat(document.forms[0].elements["lodge"+row].value);

   var meal = parseFloat(document.forms[0].elements["meal"+row].value);


   return travel+lodge+meal;

   }

/* calcTotal() 
Calculates the total cost of the travel */

function calcTotal() {

//create a variable totalEXP

var totalExp = 0;

//create a for loop that runs 1 t0 4

    for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++)

// increase the value of totalExp by value returned for calcRow


      {  totalExp += calcRow(i);}

 return totalExp;

}

/* upDate() 
Updates the total travel cost */

function update() {

//create a variable numRegExp

    var numRegExp = /^\d*(\.\d{0,2})?$/;

// Test weather the currently selected object matches the numRegExp pattern

    if (numRegExp.test(this.value)){

// Display the value of the current object to 2 decimal places.

    parseInt(this.value).toFixed(2);

//insert a for loop that runs 1 to 4 for all the expense rows in the form


    for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {

//Set the value of sub[i] field to the value returned by calcRow()

    document.forms[0].elements["sub" + i].value = calcRow(i).toFixed(2);

//set the value of the total field equal to the value returned by the calTotal() function

    document.forms[0].total.value = calcTotal().toFixed(2);

    }

    }

    //if the condition is not met display alert and change value.

   else if (numRegExp.test(this.value) == false) {

    alert("Invalid currency value");

    (this.value = "0.00");

    this.focus();
}
    

}
```

```css
body {background: white url(back.jpg) repeat-y scroll 0px 0px}
#links {position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 0px}

#main {border: 1px solid black; width: 640px; padding: 5px;
       background-color: white; margin-left: 100px; margin-top: 0px}
span {color: red; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 9pt}
table {font-size: 8pt; width: 630px; margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 0px}
th {background-color: rgb(153,204,255); text-align: left; font-weight: normal;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif}
#reporttitle {background-color: white; text-align: center; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
              font-size: 18pt; color: rgb(153,204,255); font-weight: bold}

input {width: 100%; font-size: 8pt}
select {width: 100%; font-size: 8pt}
#lname, #fname {width: 150px}
#account, #department, #project {width: 150px}

#traveltable th {text-align: center}
#subhead {width: 100px}
#travelexphead, #lodgeexphead, #mealexphead {width: 80px}
#date1, #date2, #date3, #date4 {text-align: center}
#travel1, #travel2, #travel3, #travel4 {text-align: right}
#lodge1, #lodge2, #lodge3, #lodge4 {text-align: right}
#meal1, #meal2, #meal3, #meal4 {text-align: right}
#sub1, #sub2, #sub3, #sub4,#total {text-align: right}
#traveltable #totalhead {text-align: right}

textarea {height: 100px; width: 100%}

#main #psub {text-align: center}
#main p input {width: 190px; background-color: rgb(153,204,255); color: black;
               letter-spacing: 5}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<!-- 
   New Perspectives on JavaScript, 2nd Edition
   Tutorial 5
   Case Problem 2

   Expense Report Form
   Author: Gavin Macken
   Date: 8 March `15  

   Filename:         exp.htm
   Supporting files: back.jpg, exp.css, links.jpg, logo.jpg, report.js
-->
   <title>Expense Report</title>
   <link href="exp.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   <script src = "report.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>

</head>

<body>
   <form id="expform" method="post" action="done.htm">

   <div id="links"><img src="links.jpg" alt="" /></div>

   <div id="main">
      <p><img src="logo.jpg" alt="DeLong Enterprises" /></p>

      <table cellspacing="2">
      <tr>
         <th colspan="5" id="reporttitle">Travel Expense Report</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th>Name (Last)<span>*</span></th>
         <th>(First)<span>*</span></th>
         <th>(Initial)</th>
         <th>Account<span>*</span></th>
         <td><input name="account" id="account" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><input name="lname" id="lname"/></td>
         <td><input name="fname" id="fname"/></td>
         <td><input name="init" id="init"/></td>
         <th>Department<span>*</span></th>
         <td><input name="department" id="department" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th>Social Security Number<span>*</span></th>
         <td colspan="2"><input name="ssn" id="ssn" /></td>
         <th>Project<span>*</span></th>
         <td><input name="project" id="project" /></td>
      </tr>
      </table>

      <table cellspacing="2">
      <tr>
         <th>Send Check to:<span>*</span></th>
         <th>Trip Summary<span>*</span></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <textarea id="address" name="address" rows="" cols=""></textarea>
         </td>
         <td>
            <textarea id="summary" name="summary" rows="" cols=""></textarea>
         </td>
      </tr>
      </table>

      <table id="traveltable" cellspacing="2">
      <tr>
         <th id="datehead">Travel Date</th>
         <th id="travelexphead">Travel Cost</th>
         <th id="traveltypehead">Type</th>
         <th id="lodgeexphead">Lodging</th>
         <th id="mealexphead">Meals</th>
         <th id="subhead">Total</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><input name="date1" id="date1"  /></td>
         <td><input name="travel1" id="travel1" value="0.00" class="expenseEntry" /></td>
         <td><select name="traveltype1" id="traveltype1">
            <option>air</option>
            <option>auto</option>
            <option>taxi</option>
            <option>train</option>
             </select>
         </td>
         <td><input name="lodge1" id="lodge1" value="0.00" class="expenseEntry" /></td>
         <td><input name="meal1" id="meal1" value="0.00" class="expenseEntry" /></td>
         <td><input name="sub1" id="sub1" value="0.00" readonly="readonly" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><input name="date2" id="date2" /></td>
         <td><input name="travel2" id="travel2" value="0.00" class="expenseEntry" /></td>
         <td><select name="traveltype2" id="traveltype2">
             <option>air</option>
             <option>auto</option>
             <option>taxi</option>
             <option>train</option>
             </select>
         </td>
         <td><input name="lodge2" id="lodge2" value="0.00" class="expenseEntry" /></td>
         <td><input name="meal2" id="meal2" value="0.00" class="expenseEntry" /></td>
         <td><input name="sub2" id="sub2" value="0.00" readonly="readonly" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><input name="date3" id="date3" /></td>
         <td><input name="travel3" id="travel3" value="0.00" class="expenseEntry" /></td>
         <td><select name="traveltype3" id="traveltype3">
             <option>air</option>
             <option>auto</option>
             <option>taxi</option>
             <option>train</option>
             </select>
         </td>
         <td><input name="lodge3" id="lodge3" value="0.00" class="expenseEntry" /></td>
         <td><input name="meal3" id="meal3" value="0.00" class="expenseEntry" /></td>
         <td><input name="sub3" id="sub3" value="0.00" readonly="readonly" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><input name="date4" id="date4" /></td>
         <td><input name="travel4" id="travel4" value="0.00" class="expenseEntry" /></td>
         <td><select name="traveltype4" id="traveltype4">
             <option>air</option>
             <option>auto</option>
             <option>taxi</option>
             <option>train</option>
             </select>
         </td>
         <td><input name="lodge4" id="lodge4" value="0.00" class="expenseEntry" /></td>
         <td><input name="meal4" id="meal4" value="0.00" class="expenseEntry" /></td>
         <td><input name="sub4" id="sub4" value="0.00" readonly="readonly" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th colspan="5" id="totalhead">TOTAL</th>
         <td><input id="total" name="total" readonly="readonly" value="0.00" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td colspan="6"><span>* - Indicates a required field</span></td>
      </tr>
      </table>

      <p id="psub">
         <input type="submit" value="Submit Report" />
      </p>

   </div>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're testing the DOM element against the regexp, which doesn't make sense. The argument to `regx.test()` must be a string. You need to use the value of the field:

```
if (regx.test(field.value)) {
```

You're setting the `onblur` property wrong. It should be set to the `update` function, but you're calling the function at that time. It should be:

```
dataFields[i].onblur = update;
```

And you were using the `.value` property when you called `testPattern` for the `department` field. But `testPattern` expects the argument to be the element, not the value. It should be:

```
if (testPattern(document.forms[0].department, /^DEPT\d{3}$/) == false)
```

```js
window.onload = initPage;

/*initPage() 
Initializes the contents of the Web page */

function initPage() {

  //declare array variable dataFields points to input elements from the expenseEntry class

  var dataFields = new Array();

  var allElems = document.getElementsByTagName("*");

  for (var i = 0; i < allElems.length; i++) {
    if (allElems[i].className == "expenseEntry") dataFields.push(allElems[i]);
  }

  //add onblur event that runs update() function whenever focus leaves a datafield.

  for (var i = 0; i < dataFields.length; i++) {
    dataFields[i].onblur = update;
  }

  //event handler that runs validateForm() upon submitting the form.

  document.forms[0].onsubmit = validateForm;
}

/* testLength() 
Tests a field for its length. */

function testLength(field) {
  if (field.value.length == 0) {

    // Change the background color to white or yellow depending on the lenght.

    field.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    return false;
  } else field.style.backgroundColor = "white";
  return true;
}

/* testPattern() 
Tests a field for its pattern. */

function testPattern(field, regx) {
  if (regx.test(field.value)) {
    field.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    field.style.color = "black";
    return true;
  } else field.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
  field.style.color = "red";
  return false;
}

/* validateForm() 
Validates a Web form */

function validateForm() {

  var isValid = true;

  //testLength function with lname field also for fname, address, and summary to make sure an entry has been made.

  if (testLength(document.forms[0].lname) == false) {

    isValid = false;
  }

  if (testLength(document.forms[0].fname) == false) {

    isValid = false;
  }

  if (testLength(document.forms[0].address) == false) {

    isValid = false;
  }

  if (testLength(document.forms[0].summary) == false) {

    isValid = false;
  }

  //must match ACT followed by six digits

  if (testPattern(document.forms[0].account, /^ACT\d{6}$/) == false)

  {
    isValid = false;
  }

  //dept field. regx should match DEPT followed by three digits

  if (testPattern(document.forms[0].department, /^DEPT\d{3}$/) == false)

  {
    isValid = false;
  }

  //Project field with regx should match PROJ followed by five digits

  if (testPattern(document.forms[0].project, /^PROJ\d{5}$/) == false)

  {
    isValid = false;
  }

  //call testPattern function to test SSN.  match 9 digits or text string

  if (testPattern(document.forms[0].ssn, /^\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}$/) == false) {
    isValid = false;
  }

  if (isValid == false)

  {
    alert("Please fill out all required fields in the proper format.");
  }

  return isValid;
}

/* calcRow 
Calculates the costs within one row of the travel report */

function calcRow(row) {

  var travel = parseFloat(document.forms[0].elements["travel" + row].value);

  var lodge = parseFloat(document.forms[0].elements["lodge" + row].value);

  var meal = parseFloat(document.forms[0].elements["meal" + row].value);


  return travel + lodge + meal;

}

/* calcTotal() 
Calculates the total cost of the travel */

function calcTotal() {

  //create a variable totalEXP

  var totalExp = 0;

  //create a for loop that runs 1 t0 4

  for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++)

  // increase the value of totalExp by value returned for calcRow


  {
    totalExp += calcRow(i);
  }

  return totalExp;

}

/* upDate() 
Updates the total travel cost */

function update() {

  //create a variable numRegExp

  var numRegExp = /^\d*(\.\d{0,2})?$/;

  // Test weather the currently selected object matches the numRegExp pattern

  if (numRegExp.test(this.value)) {

    // Display the value of the current object to 2 decimal places.

    parseInt(this.value).toFixed(2);

    //insert a for loop that runs 1 to 4 for all the expense rows in the form


    for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {

      //Set the value of sub[i] field to the value returned by calcRow()

      document.forms[0].elements["sub" + i].value = calcRow(i).toFixed(2);

      //set the value of the total field equal to the value returned by the calTotal() function

      document.forms[0].total.value = calcTotal().toFixed(2);

    }

  }

  //if the condition is not met display alert and change value.
  else if (numRegExp.test(this.value) == false) {

    alert("Invalid currency value");

    (this.value = "0.00");

    this.focus();
  }


}
```

```css
body {
  background: white url(back.jpg) repeat-y scroll 0px 0px
}
#links {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 0px
}
#main {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 640px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: white;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: 0px
}
span {
  color: red;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 9pt
}
table {
  font-size: 8pt;
  width: 630px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 0px
}
th {
  background-color: rgb(153, 204, 255);
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif
}
#reporttitle {
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18pt;
  color: rgb(153, 204, 255);
  font-weight: bold
}
input {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 8pt
}
select {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 8pt
}
#lname,
#fname {
  width: 150px
}
#account,
#department,
#project {
  width: 150px
}
#traveltable th {
  text-align: center
}
#subhead {
  width: 100px
}
#travelexphead,
#lodgeexphead,
#mealexphead {
  width: 80px
}
#date1,
#date2,
#date3,
#date4 {
  text-align: center
}
#travel1,
#travel2,
#travel3,
#travel4 {
  text-align: right
}
#lodge1,
#lodge2,
#lodge3,
#lodge4 {
  text-align: right
}
#meal1,
#meal2,
#meal3,
#meal4 {
  text-align: right
}
#sub1,
#sub2,
#sub3,
#sub4,
#total {
  text-align: right
}
#traveltable #totalhead {
  text-align: right
}
textarea {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%
}
#main #psub {
  text-align: center
}
#main p input {
  width: 190px;
  background-color: rgb(153, 204, 255);
  color: black;
  letter-spacing: 5
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <!-- 
   New Perspectives on JavaScript, 2nd Edition
   Tutorial 5
   Case Problem 2

   Expense Report Form
   Author: Gavin Macken
   Date: 8 March `15  

   Filename:         exp.htm
   Supporting files: back.jpg, exp.css, links.jpg, logo.jpg, report.js
-->
  <title>Expense Report</title>
  <link href="exp.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="report.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <form id="expform" method="post" action="done.htm">

    <div id="links">
      <img src="links.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>

    <div id="main">
      <p>
        <img src="logo.jpg" alt="DeLong Enterprises" />
      </p>

      <table cellspacing="2">
        <tr>
          <th colspan="5" id="reporttitle">Travel Expense Report</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Name (Last)<span>*</span>
          </th>
          <th>(First)<span>*</span>
          </th>
          <th>(Initial)</th>
          <th>Account<span>*</span>
          </th>
          <td>
            <input name="account" id="account" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input name="lname" id="lname" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input name="fname" id="fname" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input name="init" id="init" />
          </td>
          <th>Department<span>*</span>
          </th>
          <td>
            <input name="department" id="department" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Social Security Number<span>*</span>
          </th>
          <td colspan="2">
            <input name="ssn" id="ssn" />
          </td>
          <th>Project<span>*</span>
          </th>
          <td>
            <input name="project" id="project" />
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>

      <table cellspacing="2">
        <tr>
          <th>Send Check to:<span>*</span>
          </th>
          <th>Trip Summary<span>*</span>
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <textarea id="address" name="address" rows="" cols=""></textarea>
          </td>
          <td>
            <textarea id="summary" name="summary" rows="" cols=""></textarea>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>

      <table id="traveltable" cellspacing="2">
        <tr>
          <th id="datehead">Travel Date</th>
          <th id="travelexphead">Travel Cost</th>
          <th id="traveltypehead">Type</th>
          <th id="lodgeexphead">Lodging</th>
          <th id="mealexphead">Meals</th>
          <th id="subhead">Total</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input name="date1" id="date1" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input name="travel1" id="travel1" value="0.00" class="expenseEntry" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <select name="traveltype1" id="traveltype1">
              <option>air</option>
              <option>auto</option>
              <option>taxi</option>
              <option>train</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input name="lodge1" id="lodge1" value="0.00" class="expenseEntry" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input name="meal1" id="meal1" value="0.00" class="expenseEntry" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input name="sub1" id="sub1" value="0.00" readonly="readonly" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input name="date2" id="date2" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input name="travel2" id="travel2" value="0.00" class="expenseEntry" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <select name="traveltype2" id="traveltype2">
              <option>air</option>
              <option>auto</option>
              <option>taxi</option>
              <option>train</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input name="lodge2" id="lodge2" value="0.00" class="expenseEntry" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input name="meal2" id="meal2" value="0.00" class="expenseEntry" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input name="sub2" id="sub2" value="0.00" readonly="readonly" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input name="date3" id="date3" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input name="travel3" id="travel3" value="0.00" class="expenseEntry" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <select name="traveltype3" id="traveltype3">
              <option>air</option>
              <option>auto</option>
              <option>taxi</option>
              <option>train</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input name="lodge3" id="lodge3" value="0.00" class="expenseEntry" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input name="meal3" id="meal3" value="0.00" class="expenseEntry" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input name="sub3" id="sub3" value="0.00" readonly="readonly" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input name="date4" id="date4" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input name="travel4" id="travel4" value="0.00" class="expenseEntry" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <select name="traveltype4" id="traveltype4">
              <option>air</option>
              <option>auto</option>
              <option>taxi</option>
              <option>train</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input name="lodge4" id="lodge4" value="0.00" class="expenseEntry" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input name="meal4" id="meal4" value="0.00" class="expenseEntry" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input name="sub4" id="sub4" value="0.00" readonly="readonly" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th colspan="5" id="totalhead">TOTAL</th>
          <td>
            <input id="total" name="total" readonly="readonly" value="0.00" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="6"><span>* - Indicates a required field</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>

      <p id="psub">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit Report" />
      </p>

    </div>

  </form>
</body>

</html>
```